# Projecting a collection/sequence into a single Record

Tags: f#

I'm parsing HTML (via HAP) and am now parsing specific table column content per row (a collection of TD elements)

Note: Not using FSharp.Data's HTML parser as it is broken with html that contains `<Script>` code that cause the CSS Selectors to fail (known issue)

The type that I am trying to map a row of data into (10 "columns" of varying types) :

```
type DailyRow = { C0: string; C1: string; C2: int; C3: decimal; C4: string; C5: string; C6: int; C7: decimal; C8: decimal; C9: int }
```

My ugly but working function that maps column positions into the record field (yes, anything that does not parse correctly should explode):

```
let dailyRow = fun (record:DailyRow, column:int, node:HtmlNode) ->
        printfn "dailyRow: Column %i has value %s" column node.InnerText
        match column with 
        | 0 -> {record with C0 = node.InnerText }
        | 1 -> {record with C1 = node.InnerText }
        | 2 -> {record with C2 = (node.InnerText |> int) }
        | 3 -> {record with C3 = Decimal.Parse(node.InnerText, NumberStyles.Currency) }
        | 4 -> {record with C4 = node.InnerText }
        | 5 -> {record with C5 = node.InnerText }
        | 6 -> {record with C6 = Int32.Parse(node.InnerText, NumberStyles.AllowThousands) }
        | 7 -> {record with C7 = Decimal.Parse(node.InnerText, NumberStyles.Currency) }
        | 8 -> {record with C8 = Decimal.Parse(node.InnerText, NumberStyles.Currency) }
        | 9 -> {record with C9 = (node.InnerText |> int) }
        | _ -> raise (System.MissingFieldException("New Field in Chart Data Found: " + column.ToString()))
```

Some test code:

```
let chartRow = { C0 = ""; C1 = ""; C2 = 0; C3 = 0.0M; C4 = "" ; C5 = ""; C6 = 0; C7 = 0.0M; C8 = 0.0M; C9 = 0 }
let columnsToParse = row.SelectNodes "td" // 1 row of 10 columns
let x = columnsToParse
                |> Seq.mapi (fun i x -> dailyRow(chartRow, i, x))
```

The issue, since I am passing in a immutable record and receiving a new record from the dailyRow function via `Seq.mapi` (using the index to map to the column number), I will end up with 10 records, each with one of their values property set.

In C# I would just pass `dailyRow` a ref'd object and update it in place, what would be the F# idiomatic way of handling this?

Comment: Couldn't you just `fold` over it and accumulate the single resultant object?

Comment: Just do this pretty much like you'd do it in C#, and then your code will be much simpler, and idiomatic. The ´record with´ construct can accept more than one field at a time, but in this case it's better to instantiate the record inside a function since after all you will assign all fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest option, if you don't mind an array allocation:

```
let nodes = seq [...]
let arr = nodes |> Seq.map (fun n -> n.InnerText) |> Array.ofSeq
let record = 
    { C0 = arr.[0]
      C1 = arr.[1]
      C2 = int arr.[2]
      C3 = Decimal.Parse(arr.[3], NumberStyles.Currency)
      C4 = arr.[4]
      C5 = arr.[5]
      C6 = Int32.Parse(arr.[6], NumberStyles.AllowThousands)
      C7 = Decimal.Parse(arr.[7], NumberStyles.Currency)
      C8 = Decimal.Parse(arr.[8], NumberStyles.Currency)
      C9 = int arr.[9] }
```

Comment: Thanks , never thought about the `Array.ofSeq` to use the array's index to map that columns to record fields...so simple... head bang... I tried folding, different mapping, etc... and this was the simplest (and fastest and ended up being the lowest GC)... Occam's razor 